# Select multiple classes with same property

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have multiple classes like this with same property:

```
.class1 > div{
  background-color: red;
}
```

I try to reduce the CSS code with:

```
.class1, .class2, .class3 > div{
  background-color: red;
}
```

But it doesn't work properly, it only takes the last class in this case `.class3`.

Is there a way to properly do this?

Comment: I have completed the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38337341/483779) with all the details I could find, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the child div selected for each of the classes, you'll need to specify it with the selector for each class like so:

**CSS**

```
.class1 > div, .class2 > div, .class3 > div {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

[Single Selector (Wrong)](https://jsfiddle.net/mf1jg1sv/3/)

[Selector For Each Class (Right)](https://jsfiddle.net/mf1jg1sv/2/)

Comment: ah think i could escape that thanks for your quick reply Hunter

Comment: @michellompret, No problem! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to use `:matches` pseudo-class in CSS Selectors Level 4.

```
:matches(.class1, .class2, .class3) > div {
  ...
}
```

It only works in certain browsers at the moment, e.g. latest Apple Safari.

For now, you will have to use the *old* syntax, `:any` with their respective prefix in Firefox and Chrome. Not supported in IE and Edge.

```
:-moz-any(.class1, .class2, .class3) > div { ... }
:-webkit-any(.class1, .class2, .class3) > div { ... }
```

```css
:-moz-any(.class1, .class2, .class3) > div {
  background: aqua;
}
:-webkit-any(.class1, .class2, .class3) > div {
  background: aqua;
}
:matches(.class1, .class2, .class3) > div {
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1"><div>1</div></div>
<div class="class2"><div>2</div></div>
<div class="class3"><div>3</div></div>
<div class="class4"><div>4</div></div>
<div class="class5"><div>5</div></div>
```

Hopefully, the standard `:matches` will be available in all the major browsers in the near future. Other than that, please write the  whole selectors for each one and separate them with commas:

```
.class1 > div,
.class2 > div,
.class3 > div {
  ...
}
```

References:

- [4.2. The Matches-Any Pseudo-class: :matches()](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#matches)
- [Complex CSS Selectors Inside Selectors](https://webkit.org/blog/3615/css-selectors-inside-selectors-discover-matches-not-and-nth-child/)
- [Can I use :matches() CSS pseudo-class](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-matches-pseudo)