# Condensing CSS class rules

Tags: css

I have code like:

```
#header button active:hover, #footer button active:hover {
    color: purple;
}
```

Instead of having to list all the sub-classes/elements when only `#header/#footer` are different, is it possible to do something like:

```
(#header|#footer) button active:hover {
    color: purple;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38337341/483779

Comment: Well you could also add a common class to your header and footer and style off that perhaps call the class [marginals](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24060/what-word-defines-a-category-suited-for-both-header-and-footer). Thus you end up with `.marginals buton active:hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah there's a matches pseudo class, but if you're hoping it will save you some typing it still needs vendor prefixes you'd have to duplicate and the support isn't great.

```
:matches(#header, #footer) button active:hover {
  color: purple;
}
:-webkit-any(#header, #footer) button active:hover {
  color: purple;
}
:-moz-any(#header, #footer) button active:hover {
  color: purple;
}
```

So as you can see it ends up being more verbose than just adding the comma and another selector at the moment.

Comment: No love for Microsoft browsers then? http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-matches-pseudo. Well you did mention support wasn't great.